# Problem connecting to Tor network through Okhttp client

Tags: java, android, websocket, okhttp, tor

I'm developing an android app which needs to connect to a server using Websocket through Tor network. My Tor library is
https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library

My Httpclient is https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/
The problem is when i use Orbot it works, but with this Tor proxy library it somewhat "hangs" and a message is displayed

**I/*oxyManagerEventHandler: message: severity: WARN, msg: Invalid onion hostname [scrubbed]; rejecting**

What is the cause of this?
[The message being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHIQI.jpg)

[The code which doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpUON.jpg)

[The code which works with orbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdwYo.jpg)

Comment: Is it literally `[scrubbed]`? Could you share the structure of the hostname otherwise?

Comment: Isn't this message coming from your proxy server?
https://github.com/torproject/tor/commit/258b980331f4a6c208144b80df4d4ce7de5caa58#diff-ebe86d21b68418333d8c29fccfb1c53b9d9c081c3775c0b4ae7ab16f5bb77fe8

Basically logging the Headers with https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor should help you here.